# Unable to bind latest data from http call to typeahead

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to implement a simple bootstrap typeahead where the response is getting fetched via a http call.I am receiving the response perfectly but it seems the latest value from the service call is not getting bound to scope variable from which typeahead is reading.

$scope.onChangeCallBack = function(viewValue) {

```
        var program = $scope.program.name;
        var occupancyType = $scope.occupancyType.name;
        var isStorage = $scope.isBuildingStorage;
        var isFranchise = $scope.isFranchise;
        var isLeased = $scope.isLeased;
        var isBarBuilding=$scope.isBarBuilding;
        console.log("program:"+program+"//occupancyType:"+occupancyType+"//isStorage:"+isStorage+"//isFranchise:"+isFranchise+"//+isBarBuilding"+isBarBuilding+"//viewValue"+viewValue);
        var param =
        {
          searchString: viewValue,
          filterCriteria: {
              isBar: true/*isBarBuilding*/,
              isFranchise: false/*isFranchise*/,
              isMercantile: true/*isLeased*/,
              program: program,
              occupancyType:"tennat"
             }
        }
        var promise =  AEBusinessOwnerService.getBuildingClassification(param);
        promise.then(function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data.results));
          $sccope.classificationTypeAhead  = data.results;
           });

      };
```

The search result that get displayed after 4 words are keyed in is visible only after typing the 5th character.I am not sure whats missing.

Comment: Have you yet fixed the typo in your code? Inside the promise you have $sccope.classificationTypeAhead. $scope is misspelled.

Comment: Yes I fixed it.-Ranjan

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd guess that `AEBusinessOwnerService.getBuildingClassification` isn't returning a promise that's integrated with Angular's digest cycle (ie. something based on $q).  Try doing this:

```
promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.results));
        $scope.classificationTypeAhead  = data.results;
    });
});
```

Comment: If I do as above i get the error as Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress-Ranjan

Comment: Then `AEBusinessOwnerService.getBuildingClassification` is doing that for you, and this isn't the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supporting answer to Jonathan's but I can't comment yet so:

```
promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.results));
        $scope.classificationTypeAhead  = data.results;
    });
});
```

> If I do as above i get the error as Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest
>   already in progress

As the error stated, a $digest is in progress, you can solve it by doing this

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.results));
        $scope.classificationTypeAhead  = data.results;
    });
}
```